# Approximating giant polynomial expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation, approximation

Suppose I have a giant polynomial expression analogous to

$$
F=a_1xX^6+a_2x^2X^5+a_3x^3X^4+a_4x^4X^3+a_5x^5X^2+a_6x^6X
$$

and it is true that $X \gg x$. Let it be enough for me to approximate this expression up to order $(\frac{x}{X})^3$, so that

$$
F \approx a_1xX^6+a_2x^2X^5+a_3x^3X^4.
$$

What is the cleanest way to do something like this? Bear in mind that the expression is not in the neat form of the first equation.

I suppose the most obvious way would be to write a list of terms after expanding the expression and cut out every term of the form $a_ix^{i_x}X^{i_X}$ such that $i_x\geq O$ (where $O$ is the order of approximation) *and* $N-i_X\geq O$, but I wonder if there isn't a smarter way.

Comment: Is your actual polynomial homogeneous, like the one shown? A test case (in code) might help get folks to participate (e.g. `Expand@Fold[FromDigits, SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; i + j == 7 :> RandomInteger[{1, 9}], {7, 7}], {x, y}]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the relationship between $x$ and $X$ explicit, in the sense that we want $|x/X|\ll1$ instead of simply assuming that $x$ is small, we can set $z=x/X$ and series-expand for small $z$:

```
F = Sum[a[i] * x^i * X^(7 - i), {i, 6}];

Series[F /. x -> z*X, {z, 0, 3}]
(*    a[1] X^7 z + a[2] X^7 z^2 + a[3] X^7 z^3 + O[z]^4    *)
```

In practice this is pretty much the same as what @MichaelSeifert suggests, but behind the scenes it is more explicit about the relationship between $x$ and $X$. In more complicated situations this may make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the terms up to a given order in one of the polynomial's variables, you could just use `Series` and `Normal`:

```
Series[expr, {x, 0, 3}]
Normal[%]
```

`Series` returns a result in terms of `SeriesData` objects, which include `O[x^n]` terms that allow Mathematica to keep track of the validity of the approximation.  `Normal` takes a `SeriesData` object and returns just the explicit polynomial terms.